# Vuelidate - shaking the incorrect input field

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Take a look at Basic form at [Vuelidate documentation](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form). If the rule is broken (text is too short), the label is red, then eror message appears and the input field shakes for a while. How is this done? I have copied the source code sample and the shaking effect is not there. I cannot even simulate it with an official fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/so89zmpe/2/

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.name.$error }">
  <label class="form__label">Name</label>
  <input class="form__input" v-model.trim="$v.name.$model"/>
</div>
```

I cannot find anything relevant in Chrome developer
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open DevTools > Animations tab, you can see that there's an animation name of `shakeError` applied on `.form-group.form-group--error`:

[image]

Here's the definition of `shakeError`:

```
@keyframes shakeError {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0); }
  15% {
    transform: translateX(0.375rem); }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-0.375rem); }
  45% {
    transform: translateX(0.375rem); }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(-0.375rem); }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0.375rem); }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(-0.375rem); }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0); } }
```

And then,

```
.form-group--alert,
.form-group--error {
  animation-name: shakeError;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; }
```

You can check the Sources tab of https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form for a `docs.scss` file to dig in deeper.

Comment: Thank I, have managed it: https://jsfiddle.net/literakl/bhL6aod9/7/

Comment: Is this a part of the vuelidate library that I can import? Or do I need to copy paste all the css to my project?

Comment: @LeosLiterak This is custom styling, I believe. You can copy the above CSS and it should work.

Comment: @LeosLiterak 

Comment: true, there is co CSS in the library